# Button to display text from SecondActivity in MainActivity

Tags: android

I have a class `MainActivity.java` associated with a layout `activity_main.xml`. In this layout I have a `TextView` whose id is "textView". I have a second Activity called `SecondActivity.java` and in this Activity I have a `Button`. When I click the button, I want to set the text of the `TextView` in the `MainActivity`. How can I do this ? The simple:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText("Some Text");
```

doesn't seem to work...

Comment: start second activity with StartActivityForResult(intent).

Answer (score 0):

One Way :

When you click the button use a "SharedPreference" to save an indicator/condition/state.

In onResume of the main activity check the state and update your text.

Comment: You can also pass data between activities by adding an "Extra" to the starting intent.